# How to override the OpenMp runtime scheduling policy using OMP_SCHEDULE environment variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

I have an openMP parallel for loop of the form

```
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < myArray.size() ; i++)
{
  //some code here
}
```

In other words by default this loop uses dynamic scheduling. However if the user specifies the OMP_SCHEDULE environment variable I want to be able to override the dynamic policy with whatever policy is specified in OMP_SCHEDULE. How can this be done? In other words if OMP_SCHEDULE is not specified I want to use a dynamic schedule by default. It is my understanding that in the above code, because I have specified schedule(dynamic) it is going to ignore any policy specified in OMP_SCHEDULE, is this correct? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get what you want, you'll probably need to do a bit of manual intervention. During initialization, I'd add some code on this general order:

```cpp
#include <omp.h>

std::string scheduling = getenv("OMP_SCHEDULE");

// If the user didn't specify anything, set the default we want.
if (scheduling.empty()) 
   omp_set_schedule(omp_sched_dynamic, -1);
```

Then for your loop, specify `schedule(runtime)` scheduling strategy in the `#pragma`, so it'll use what was set by `OMP_SCHEDULE` environment variable, or by us above:

```cpp
#pragma omp for schedule(runtime)
for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < myArray.size() ; i++)
{
  //some code here
}
```

Passing -1 for the chunk size tells the runtime to select its default. Depending on the situation, explicitly setting a different value may improve performance (but -1 should be equivalent to not specifying the chunk size, as you did in your `#pragma`).

Comment: You have to use `#pragma omp for schedule(runtime)`. "When kind is runtime, the decision regarding scheduling is deferred until run time, and the schedule and chunk size are taken from the run-sched-var ICV. "  https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu41.html

Comment: While passing `-1` is not strictly wrong, I would suggest to pass `0`.

Comment: @Michael: Why do you prefer `0` ?  According to the specification: " For the schedule kinds *static*, *dynamic*, and *guided* the *chunk_size* is set to the value of the second argument, or to the default *chunk_size* if the value of the second argument is less than 1;"

Comment: The first number to satisfy that requirement is 0. I guess it’s a matter of style.